# Screen Share requires confirmation on the same Apple ID

Tags: icloud, apple-id, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, apple-remote-desktop

When I try to connect to my Mac Pro from my MacBook Pro (both running Catalina) via Screen Share I’m prompted to accept the request to screen share. Once I do screen share works correctly.

My issue is I need to access it without being there to accept the invitation to screen share. It’s my understanding that as long as I’m using the same Apple ID then it should just automatically connect. Note that it does this when I connect on the same local network, but not remotely.

Both machines have a login with the same full name and password but different ‘usernames’ that is the short 1 word username is different. Not sure if this is an issue in authenticating users?

Things I’ve tried

- Unlogging and re-logging in via my Apple ID on both machines
- Turning off and back on remote management and screen sharing on both machines
- Adding iCloud address as an alias to the account on both machines

The only weird thing I note is my Apple ID is a @gmail address but when requesting screen share it shows as @icloud is requesting. Hence why I added the alias above.

I can see both machines under my Apple ID as devices and can find my mac, use messages, iTunes etc perfectly on both machines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 1):

It looks like screen sharing directly via Apple ID might use the same mechanism as iMessage screen sharing, so if this other question gets an answer, the solution may work here, too.

[Automatically accept Screen Sharing invitations?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402050/automatically-accept-screen-sharing-invitations)