# How to VNC connect to a sleeping iMac?

Tags: macos, imac, sleep-wake, remote-desktop, remote-control

I use RealVNC to connect to an intel-based iMac, but it cannot wake it up if it is asleep after long inactivity. Yes, I don't change the setting to prevent from sleeping but only leave 'Wake for network access' on.
**However, the same works perfectly to connect a sleeping Mac Studio**. This obviously has the merit of letting the machine rest and saving energy.

Both 'server' machines use WiFi and the other machine used to control them is *not* necessarily within the same local network. The 'server' machines **do not have a public IP addresses**.
I tried to compare the settings like in 'Energy Saver' between the two host machines, but still have no clue.

When testing this, I noticed that I still can connect to the iMac right after (like 10 seconds) I manually put it to sleep. If I wait a few minutes, it does not work.

Comment: How long is “right after?”  Is your iMac connected to WiFi or Ethernet? Has it gone into hibernation?

Comment: @Allan Updated. I'm not sure if 1 min is enough to let it fully sleep. I just click 'sleep' and then try to connect.

Comment: I think your Mac is going into hibernation.   When you can’t connect with VNC, try pinging the machine

Comment: What operating system is being using on the machine running the RealVNC viewer?

Comment: @DavidAnderson MacOS

Comment: Have you tried the Screen Sharing application included with macOS? In testing, I found this application can wake a sleeping Mac on the same Local Area Network (LAN). With the  Screen Sharing application, you can remote login to another Mac with or without Sharing the screen. Also, you do not need permission from another user if you know the password.

Comment: @DavidAnderson With that app, the connection request needs to be manually accepted at the sleeping iMac. Not quite feasible.

Comment: You are wrong. The connect request does ***NOT have*** to be manually accepted at the sleeping iMac. To bypass manual acceptance, you do have to at least know a password. Either you did not try or if you did try, then your did not do it right.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Could you please point me to any concrete description of such a bypass that works not just within LAN? I haven't found anything useful so far, just questions like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402050/automatically-accept-screen-sharing-invitations) without answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Screen Sharing application included with macOS should be able to wake a sleeping Mac. Apple does provide instructions at the website [Share the screen of another Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-the-screen-of-another-mac-mh14066/mac). Below is an example of where I use screen sharing without needing an user to give permission at the remote server Mac. Here, I assume screen sharing is enabled on the server.

|  | Client | Server |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mac | 2011 iMac | 2018 Mac mini |
| macOS | High Sierra | Mojave |

The steps are given below.

1. Start by right clicking on the Finder icon on the dock and selecting "Connect to Server...", as shown below.

   [image: right click on Finder]
2. In the "Connect to Server" popup, enter the server ip address (or name.domain) preceeded by `vnc://`, as shown below. Next, select the `Connect` button.

[image: connect to server popup]

3. You should get a popup similar to the one shown below.

   [image: connecting popup]
4. When the popup shown below appears, enter a username and password of an account on the server, as shown below. Next, select the `Connect` button.

   [image: name and pw popup]
5. You should get a popup similar to the one shown below.

   [image: ask or login popup]
6. Choose the radio button which begins with "Log in as yourself:". Next, select the `Connect` button.

   [image: log in as yourself]
7. You should get a popup similar to the one shown below.

   [image: more connecting]
8. The following log in screen appeared. Since I know Ron Janzen is currently logged in at the server Mac, I can screen share by selecting this user.

   [image: selection screen]
9. After selecting Ron Janzen, I am prompted for Ron Janzen's password, as shown below.

   [image: Enter pw]

After entering Ron Janzen's password, I am allowed to screen share. For privacy purposes, an image has been omitted.

---

### Remote Log In without Screen Sharing

In step 8 above, I could have selected an user which is not logged in. Doing so would allow me to access a remote desktop without interfering with the current user logged in at the server Mac. For example, if I selected David Anderson in step 8 above, then the password for David Anderson's account on the server would be asked for, as shown below.

[image: david's pw]

After entering the password, the window shown below appeared.

[image: david's desktop]

Note: the server Mac has two displays. After selecting to only view the first display and selecting scaling, the following window is shown.

[image: david's diskplay 1 scaled]

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that the machines are not in the same LAN and the 'server' Mac doesn't have a public IP address if I understand correctly. Not clear what to enter in step 2. That's partially why I use RealVNC.